# Finding the Big O time complexity

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
i = 1;     
while (i <= n) {
     j = n - i;
     while (j >= 2) {
         for (k = 1; k <= j; k++) {
             s = s + Arr[k];
         }
         j = j - 2;
     }
     i = i + 1;
}
```

The part that confuses me is where it says

```
j = n - i;
while(j >= 2){
```

I'm not really sure how to show my work on that part. I'm pretty sure the algorthim is O(n^3) though.

Comment: Yes, it's `O(n^3)`. Your `while` is equivalent to `for (j = n-i; j >= 2; j -= 2)` and you can replace it with `for (j = 2; j <= n-i; j += 2)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify it a bit in order to see things more clearly:

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    for(j = n - i; j >= 2; j -= 2)
    {
        for(k = 1; k <= j; k++)
        {
            s = s + Arr[k];
        }
    }
}
```

Now things should be simpler

- `for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)` : **O(n)** [executes exactly n times, actually]
- `for(j = n - i; j >= 2; j -= 2)` : `(n-1)/2` in 1st iteration, `(n-3)/2` in the 2nd and so on... **O(n)**
- `for(k = 1; k <= j; k++)` `n-2` in 1st iteration, `n-3` in the 2nd and so on... **O(n)**
- `s = s + Arr[k];` [simple operation] : **O(1)**

Multiply every step and you get **O(n^3)**

*If you are still having trouble with it, I would suggest you run a few simulations of this code with varying `n` values and a counter inside the loops. Hopefully you'll be able to see how the **`O(n)`** is the complexity for each loop*